# Ubuntu 16.04 is booting very slow

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have very slow boot when I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04

It sometimes never boot and i have to force shutdown it pressing along on power button and open from beginning

I used `systemd-analyze blame` and i got the following

```
1min 31.254s winbind.service
1min 31.254s winbind.service
1min 31.254s winbind.service
1min 31.243s nmbd.service
1min 30.508s samba-ad-dc.service
1min 26.919s vmware.service
1min 16.574s apache2.service
 1min 4.486s mysql.service
     36.783s apparmor.service
     33.976s virtualbox.service
     26.262s udhcpd.service
     25.635s preload.service
     24.296s dev-sda1.device
     23.807s networking.service
     23.106s speech-dispatcher.service
     20.720s ModemManager.service
     17.155s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
     15.922s irqbalance.service
     13.746s apport.service
     13.373s lightdm.service
     12.647s upower.service
     10.698s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.174s keyboard-setup.service
     10.054s snapd.refresh.service
      9.695s systemd-logind.service
      9.634s alsa-restore.service
      9.632s gpu-manager.service
      9.629s rsyslog.service
      9.625s systemd-user-sessions.service
      9.459s avahi-daemon.service
      9.459s thermald.service
      9.416s grub-common.service
      9.197s colord.service
      8.910s apt-daily.service
      8.862s dev-hugepages.mount
      8.861s dev-mqueue.mount
      8.860s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      8.667s kmod-static-nodes.service
      8.645s ufw.service
      8.167s systemd-journald.service
      7.487s systemd-modules-load.service
      5.649s systemd-localed.service
      5.062s systemd-udevd.service
      3.321s console-setup.service
      3.119s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.986s NetworkManager.service
      2.181s accounts-daemon.service
      2.124s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.924s jetty.service
      1.857s plymouth-start.service
      1.708s binfmt-support.service
      1.688s polkitd.service
      1.541s setvtrgb.service
      1.283s lm-sensors.service
      1.208s bluetooth.service
      1.192s dns-clean.service
      1.032s plymouth-read-write.service
       754ms wpa_supplicant.service
       691ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       681ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       621ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       611ms systemd-sysctl.service
       600ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       460ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-21920ece\x2d32b5\x2d4739\x2da584\x2d3f27984
       369ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       358ms smbd.service
       340ms udisks2.service
       330ms systemd-random-seed.service
       267ms hddtemp.service
       236ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       236ms resolvconf.service
       208ms rc-local.service
       145ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       104ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        62ms pppd-dns.service
        51ms user@1000.service
        47ms hostapd.service
        46ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        19ms ondemand.service
        13ms vncserver.service
        11ms snapd.socket
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms systemd-rfkill.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         ESCOD
1min 31.254s winbind.service
1min 31.243s nmbd.service
1min 30.508s samba-ad-dc.service
1min 26.919s vmware.service
1min 16.574s apache2.service
 1min 4.486s mysql.service
     36.783s apparmor.service
     33.976s virtualbox.service
     26.262s udhcpd.service
     25.635s preload.service
     24.296s dev-sda1.device
     23.807s networking.service
     23.106s speech-dispatcher.service
     20.720s ModemManager.service
     17.155s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
     15.922s irqbalance.service
     13.746s apport.service
     13.373s lightdm.service
     12.647s upower.service
     10.698s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.174s keyboard-setup.service
     10.054s snapd.refresh.service
      9.695s systemd-logind.service
      9.634s alsa-restore.service
      9.632s gpu-manager.service
      9.629s rsyslog.service
      9.625s systemd-user-sessions.service
      9.459s avahi-daemon.service
      9.459s thermald.service
      9.416s grub-common.service
      9.197s colord.service
      8.910s apt-daily.service
      8.862s dev-hugepages.mount
      8.861s dev-mqueue.mount
      8.860s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      8.667s kmod-static-nodes.service
      8.645s ufw.service
      8.167s systemd-journald.service
      7.487s systemd-modules-load.service
      5.649s systemd-localed.service
      5.062s systemd-udevd.service
      3.321s console-setup.service
      3.119s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.986s NetworkManager.service
      2.181s accounts-daemon.service
      2.124s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.924s jetty.service
      1.857s plymouth-start.service
      1.708s binfmt-support.service
      1.688s polkitd.service
      1.541s setvtrgb.service
      1.283s lm-sensors.service
      1.208s bluetooth.service
      1.192s dns-clean.service
      1.032s plymouth-read-write.service
       754ms wpa_supplicant.service
       691ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       681ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       621ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       611ms systemd-sysctl.service
       600ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       460ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-21920ece\x2d32b5\x2d4739\x2da584\x2d3f27984
       369ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       358ms smbd.service
       340ms udisks2.service
       330ms systemd-random-seed.service
       267ms hddtemp.service
       236ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       236ms resolvconf.service
       208ms rc-local.service
       145ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       104ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        62ms pppd-dns.service
        51ms user@1000.service
        47ms hostapd.service
        46ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        19ms ondemand.service
        13ms vncserver.service
        11ms snapd.socket
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms systemd-rfkill.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```